# [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <router-view>, possibly module conflict?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, mdbootstrap

I am trying to use vue-router inside my project adopting from [enter link description here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-vue-js-authentication-and-route-handling-using-vue-router).

**./router/index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import VesselSearch from '../components/VesselSearch';
import Login from '../components/Login';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

let router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'vessel-search',
            component: VesselSearch,
            meta: {
                requiresAuth: true,
            }
        },
        {
            path: '/login',
            name: 'login',
            component: Login,
            meta: {
                guest: true
            }
        },
    ]
})

export default router;
```

**main.js**

```
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css'
import 'mdbvue/lib/css/mdb.min.css'
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js';
import App from './App';
import router from './router';
import InstantSearch from 'vue-instantsearch';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

Vue.use(InstantSearch);

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: {App},
  template: '<App/>',
})
```

If I check using `npm list vue-router` I got:

```
+-- mdbvue@6.7.3
| `-- vue-router@3.5.2  deduped
`-- vue-router@3.5.2
```

Seem like I have 2 vue-router module, one included in `mdbootstrap` module. If it is the problem, how can I fixed it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you were registering the router to another instance of vue and that instance does not have the main component. Here is the solution In your **router/index.js** remove the lines

```
 import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
 Vue.use(Router)
```

and in your **main.js** add these lines

```
 import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
 Vue.use(Router)
```

You check it here
https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-voice-1dutp

Comment: Hi, it is worked! But, I am still need those lines in the **router/index.js**. If I remove it, it gave me an error. I wonder why. Can you explain in detail?

Comment: Same as previous error *[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <router-view> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.*

Comment: I don't know how you structured your code. But If you keep it there and it works, I think you are fine. But you may need to look at how you are instantiating your Vue. In theory, you only need to register the router with one vue instance